# PHP database query not completing in time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php function that on page load checks the database to see if a session exists for the user that may be resuming a session. If nothing exists in the database, we start them on "Step 1" of the process. However, if they do have an active session they are returning to, we get the current step number they left off on. Here is my code:

```
<?php   
//Start the session we will use to track the activity.
session_start();

//Get the session ID from a previous session if it exists; if not, create one.
$sessionID = $_GET['session'];
$sessionID = ($sessionID ? $sessionID : session_id());

//Define some vars
$mainPage = 'wizard';
require_once('includes/header.php'); 

//Lets see if we can retrieve an active session for the user.
$objDB = new DB;
    $retrieveSession = $objDB->setStoredProc('shadowFetchUserSession')
         -> setParam("sessionID", $sessionID)   
         -> setParam("empID", $empID)    
         -> execStoredProc()
         -> parseXML();

//Do we have a session already?
if($retrieveSession->sessionData){

            //This doesnt seem to get the variable in time before the rest of the code fires.
    $currentStep = $retrieveSession->sessionData->currentStep;

}else{  

//Since we didnt get a step number from the session, lets start at 1.
    $currentStep = 1;   

//Lets add the session to the database now that we have the sessionID and the current step.
$objDB = new DB;
    $makeSession = $objDB->setStoredProc('shadowCreateSession')
         -> setParam("sessionID", $sessionID)   
         -> setParam("empID", $empID)    
         -> setParam("currentStep", $currentStep)            
         -> execStoredProc();    
}
?>
```

If you look inside this statement

```
 if($retrieveSession->sessionData){
```

The $currentStep variable seems to not be getting set before other parts of the code below this have executed.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: so it's always showing currentStep as equal to 1?

Comment: Below this code I have a loop that uses the current step it gets to print out a menu and change the class of the currently selected on which isnt happening. However if i manually set $currentStep in that else statement, it works fine making me think that it never gets it in time.

Comment: gets it in time? you are only defining/setting the $currentStep in two places currently. If it doesn't get set inside the if-statement, then you are setting it inside your else-statement, i dont see the problem....are you saying that if you take the `$currentStep = 1` line out then your code doesnt work? cuz it shouldnt work in that case....

Comment: This is what Im running after the block of code above. http://codepad.org/fKhKqpAf

Answer (score 0):

Is this as simple as you having the If Else Endif terminator in the wrong place??

```
session_start();

//Get the session ID from a previous session if it exists; if not, create one.
$sessionID = $_GET['session'];
$sessionID = ($sessionID ? $sessionID : session_id());

//Define some vars
$mainPage = 'wizard';
require_once('includes/header.php'); 

//Lets see if we can retrieve an active session for the user.
$objDB = new DB;
$retrieveSession = $objDB->setStoredProc('shadowFetchUserSession')
                         -> setParam("sessionID", $sessionID)   
                         -> setParam("empID", $empID)    
                         -> execStoredProc()
                         -> parseXML();

//Do we have a session already?
if($retrieveSession->sessionData){

    //This doesnt seem to get the variable in time before the rest of the code fires.
    $currentStep = $retrieveSession->sessionData->currentStep;
} else {  

    //Since we didnt get a step number from the session, lets start at 1.
    $currentStep = 1;   
}

//Lets add the session to the database now that we have the sessionID and the current step.
$objDB = new DB;
$makeSession = $objDB->setStoredProc('shadowCreateSession')
                     -> setParam("sessionID", $sessionID)   
                     -> setParam("empID", $empID)    
                     -> setParam("currentStep", $currentStep)            
                     -> execStoredProc();    

?>
```

If thats it, then proper indentation of code may help you identify issues in the future.

Comment: The only thing I see you did was move the last DB call outside of the else statement. Coming into this page, there could be $_GET['session'] which will use the session information from the database. If there is no session information in the database, thats the only time we run the DB insert which create it which is why I put it in the else.